# mod_rewrite issue (multiple slashes address?)

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm no regex expert and I'm trying to implement on a website a social login system that may or may not redirect the user to the page where he was before loggin in.

Like so, for no redirection:

```
RewriteRule ^login/([^/]+)$ login.php?p=$1 [L]
```

http://example.com/login/Facebook >> the page does it stuff and goes to index (default behaviour).

or like this for redirection (p = provider; r= redirect relative path):

```
RewriteRule ^login/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ login.php?p=$1&r=$2 [L]
```

Works great if the user is on a page like http://example.com/info that is generated by the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^info$ users_infosystem.php [L]
```

I'm having problem when the user is on a page like http://example.com/gallery/galleryname

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/]+)$ galery.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Any Help?

EDIT: Just occured me ... I don't know if the $ char is the delimeter that marks the end and taking it off makes the rule accept everythings that is after the ([^/]+) bit.

Also: Doesn't the ([^/]+) bit match everything but a forward slash?

Comment: You are correct with the last two statements. `$` ends the expression and `([^/]+)` matches all characters excluding forward slashes. Your rule (`gallery/([^/]+)`) should match `gallery/galleryname`. What is the actual problem there? Throwing a 404?

Comment: @MikeRockett: Yup. It's throwing a 404 if the URL gets a lot of "sub-folders" eg http://example.com/gallery/galleryname/subgallery

Comment: @AfonsoGomes `example.com/gallery/galleryname/subgallery`  is not the same as `example.com/gallery/galleryname/` what is working and what's not? Because the current rule you have will not work for additional sub folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having problem when the user is on a page like

That is a very vague sentence. You don't actually say what the problem is. What about your rule is not working? Also didn't paste your entire htaccess file, you pasted bits and pieces so we don't even know what order your rules are in or if there are other rules.

I don't see an issue with *these* rules. These rules should work. They all match something different. Also you can make the `/` optional using the `?` after it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^login/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ login.php?p=$1&r=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^login/([^/]+)/?$ login.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^info/?$ users_infosystem.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/]+)/?$ galery.php?name=$1 [L]
```

The last rule will match `http://example.com/gallery/galleryname` with or without a `/` at the end.

Comment: Sorry about that. tryed to be as simples and concise as possible as this htaccess files tend to be really big. I tryed to paste the bits that described best the problem (and I took special notice about the exact order they are in the htaccess file). The last rule is throwing me 404s. Ty for taking the time @Panama Jack.  I'll test your answer in a bit and edit my question to be clearer.

Comment: Sorry about the delay in the response. been upgrading from ADSL to Fiber Optic and had to spend some days without access. I now notice I could have asked my question in a much more enlighting way, but fortunatelly your rule to compensate the presence or not of forward slash at the end of the URL solved my redirect issue. Thanks so much for the time you took with this. Upvoted and accepted! Cheers.